# I want to use blender to teach calculus with the python math, can this bpy ver. do this?

Tags: python

Derivative and such Integral Calculus symbols etc. available in the math utilities or can they be imported from one of the many available?

Comment: How do you plan to use Blender or python in teaching? Python is scripted without calculus symbols per se, while to illustrate various formulas in viewport and rendering you could import the symbols via font or .svg files?